# Is there any way to move your dragonvale park to another facebook account?

Tags: dragonvale

I've realized that my dragonvale is linked to my personal fb account and I want to have a separate account just for dragonvale. Is there anyway to transfer my park?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.backflipstudios.com/help/androidfaq/ has this to say:

> DragonVale park progress is stored on our servers for Android devices when the park is associated with a Facebook account.  If you would like to associate your Local park with your Facebook account, please follow these steps (please note that this is a permanent choice and once you associate your Local park to your Facebook account, this cannot be undone)...

So you cannot undo the link yourself. It's unlikely that support has the capability to do this as well. You'll have to start a new park, sorry.